# ¿Cómo se tratan los acentos en el orden alfabético?

Tags: acentuación, orden-de-palabras, alfabeto

¿Cómo se ordenan alfabéticamente las palabras que únicamente se diferencian por la presencia o no de acento, o por la posición de este en la palabra?

Por ejemplo:  amoniaco y amoníaco, o júbilo, jubilo y jubiló

Answer (score 6):

No parece que haya una norma con carácter oficial pero segun la ([RAE](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1026720209539919872)), la vocal sin acento precede *normalmente* a la vocal con acento :

> amoniaco
> amoníaco
> ...
> jubilo
> jubiló
> júbilo

Convenciones más detalladas se encuentran en el sitio web de la [UOC](https://www.uoc.edu/portal/es/servei-linguistic/convencions/ordenacio-alfabetica/index.html):

> *Las palabras que llevan tilde o diéresis suelen clasificarse como si no la llevasen. En el caso de palabras que solo se distinguen por la tilde o la diéresis (sea porque una lleva alguno de estos signos y la otra no, sea porque los llevan diferentes), el orden de clasificación es el siguiente:
> 1.º: sin tilde
> 2.º: con tilde
> 3.º: con diéresis*

y también en [Wikilengua](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ordenaci%C3%B3n_alfab%C3%A9tica):

> *No hay criterio establecido en español para la alfabetización de letras con diacríticos (á, ü), pero normalmente suelen ir tras la forma sin acento (cómo detrás de como). Las mayúsculas suelen ir tras las minúsculas y también las formas en redonda suelen preceder a las variantes en cursiva.*

El DLC de 1925 no sigue esta convención:

[image]

mientras que el DLE 2001 lo hace:

[image]

Comment: Correcto. Dado que los casos en los que la única diferencia es el acento son bastante raros, es probable que la cuestión no se considerara muy importante.

Comment: En cualquier orden, no será difícil encontrar las palabras en un diccionario. De toda manera, también hay palabras homógrafas. Su orden no puede ser sino arbitrario

Comment: Lo entiendo. Lo que digo es que por ejemplo hay tres palabras que se escriben *lama* en español, su orden es arbitrario pero no nos impide encontrarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que se usan computadores el orden de las palabras con vocales acentuadas depende principalmente del código que tenga esa vocal en la página de código (codepage) que se esté usando, a menos que se utilice un programa especializado que tenga en cuenta las reglas de ordenación del español, y en particular de la "Ñ".

Por ejemplo en la página de códigos [ISO-8859-Latin-1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), que es de 1 byte por caracter, las vocales acentuadas e incluso la "ñ" o la "Ñ" tiene códigos superiores a 128.

Por ejemplo este es el resultado de ordenas estas palabra según el código numérico de cada letra:

```
PALABRA|CODIGOS en ISO-8601-Latin-1
jubilo |106,117,98,105,108,111
jubilp |106,117,98,105,108,112
jubilñ |106,117,98,105,108,241    
jubiló |106,117,98,105,108,243
júbilo |106,250,98,105,108,111
```

Obsérvese por ejemplo que la "ñ" (minúscula) está después de la "p".

Esta sería la verdadera razón para la decisión de la RAE de eliminar el ordenamiento particular que se usaba para la "CH" después de la "C" y antes de "D" y la "LL" después de "L" y antes de "M", a favor del ordenamiento que se da con los computadores ya que esto simplifica y no requiere algoritmos de ordenamiento especializados, claro excepto el caso de la "Ñ" que requiere tratamiento particular.