# ¿Cómo se trata la diéresis en el orden alfabético?

Tags: ortografía, orden-de-palabras, alfabeto

¿Cómo se trata la diéresis en el orden alfabético de las palabras que solo difieren en ésta? Por ejemplo:

- [**guito**](https://dle.rae.es/guito) y [**güito**](https://dle.rae.es/g%C3%BCito)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [¿Cómo se tratan los acentos en el orden alfabético?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39853/c%c3%b3mo-se-tratan-los-acentos-en-el-orden-alfab%c3%a9tico)

Comment: Me parece que sí: *el orden de clasificación es el siguiente: 1.º: sin tilde 2.º: con tilde 3.º: con diéresis*

Answer (score 1):

No he encontrado ningún documento "oficial" en que se aclare.

Consultando **guito** y **güito** en diveros diccionarios de la DLE accesibles a través del NTTLE, parece que tampoco hay un acuerdo en la RAE. Así en los diccionarios de 1970 y 1984, viene guito antes que güito:

[image]

[image]

mientras que en la edición de 1992 es al revés, primero güito y luego guito:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que encontré en en este artículo, no hay [trato especial al diéresis ni a los acentos](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ordenaci%C3%B3n_alfab%C3%A9tica):

> **No hay criterio establecido en español para la alfabetización de
> letras con diacríticos (á, ü), pero normalmente suelen ir tras la
> forma sin acento (cómo detrás de como).** Las mayúsculas suelen ir tras
> las minúsculas y también las formas en redonda suelen preceder a las
> variantes en cursiva. De este modo, podríamos tener, por ejemplo, el
> siguiente orden:
>
> a A   á   Á   a   A   á   Á 
> El orden exacto dependerá de las necesidades de la
> obra y el estilo editorial.
> El orden alfabético del español varía en algunos puntos del de otras
> lenguas que emplean el alfabeto latino. Por ejemplo:

[También](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ordenaci%C3%B3n_alfab%C3%A9tica#Diferencias_del_orden_con_otras_lenguas),

- ñ en español va tras la n, pero va dentro de la n en bretón;
- ch en checo va tras la h, pero va dentro de la c en español (a partir de
  1994, ya que hasta entonces iba tras la c)
- **en alemán, ü se alfabetiza como si fuera ue, mientras que en español no tiene  tratamiento especial.**